# DigitalPersona UareU SDK JavaFX EXE Application doesn't run

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, exe, fingerprint

I have a JavaFX Application that uses the UareU SDK. Everything works perfect in eclipse and packaged as a jar everything is perfect. When I package it as an EXE however, the code does not run, and it simply doesn't work. The application doesn't freeze and no errors are written. My log file is not even updated for an error or anything.

When logging line per line it seems to freeze right when I try to load the following:...

```
AppUtils.logInfo("Finger stuff start");
      try {
         AppUtils.logInfo("Going to get readers");
         m_collection = UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection();
         AppUtils.logInfo("Got global reader collection");
         m_collection.GetReaders();
         AppUtils.logInfo("Got reader collection");
      } catch (UareUException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         AppUtils.logError("Cannot get readers");
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

The log "'Going to get readers'" is written and then it simply stops. 
I have the SDK installed and as I said, the jar file works as expected. Is the exe not looking for the dll correctly or any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Please, how did you get the uareu SDK?